# How to take a polynomial as input in matlab?

Tags: matlab

I want to take a polynomial p as input from user in matlab for a given degree (specified by the user each time) such that the polynomial is input one element at a time into a matrix at each index from 1 to n. where n is the polynomial degree. was tryin to do something like this but m stuck

```
     for M = 1:n
        p[n] = input('polynomial')
        p
     end
```

How should I input a polynomial coefficient at each index of matrix i.e. how to reach each index position?

Comment: Indices in MATLAB are accessed using `p(n)`, not `p[n]`. Also, I think you should be assigning input to `p(M)` instead of `p(n)`

Comment: thanks. making the corrections u pointed out, i still get an error for the line: for M = 1:n

Comment: Can you show the error? Also, what is n? I tried this code and it is working as expected.

Comment: it just says error in line at M = 1:n. n is a number say n = 4 or what ever degree the polynomial to be entered has.

Comment: There should be something more, like invalid value or type for the variable `n`. Print the value of `n` before the loop to check for valid value. Check the type of `n` using the command `whos n;`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Instead of using a loop, you can take a polynomial as input using the following method:

```
p = input('Enter a polynomial in [] brackets');
```

Now the user should enter the polynomial like this:

```
[2, 4, 3, 8];
```

Then you can calculate its degree using the `length` command:

```
n = length(p);
```

Comment: The important thing is to learn to avoid loops for such mundane tasks. MATLAB does not need a loop there.

Comment: But if i want to know the degree of the polynomial, that would always be one less than the length right?